# Split screen into 4 quadrants with a border around each

Tags: html, css

I have split my screen into 4 quadrants.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="aqua pull-left"></div>

        <div class="blue pull-right" ></div>

        <div class="green pull-left bottom"></div>

        <div class="tan pull-right bottom"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: black;
}

div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

I want a black border around each one of my squares.  When I add a border, then my squares line up vertically, while alternating on the left and right of the screen.  I know this is a simple fix, but have been stuck at it for a while.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The border causes the divs to have a total width of more than 50%. Either make them somewhat smaller than 50%, or use the [box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property if your browser supports it.

Comment: Borders add additional pixels to the width of div. If border is 1px wide, it adds 2px to the width. You can change the width of divs to 49% or to exact value if possible to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border causes the width of the `div` elements to increase forcing them on to the next line.  You can account for the border by specifying a negative `margin` on the `div`.

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px -1px;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/zB3zf/

Comment: This worked beautifully, but why did you only add a negative margin on the right and left?  How come it didnt need the same thing on the top and bottom?

Comment: Because the top and bottom are not going to force the quandrant on a new line, they will just increase the height, so the actual height of the quadrant is 50% + 1px.  Depending on your use case you may need to adjust the negative margin to the top and bottom.

Comment: Box-sizing would be a better solution if you're not worried about >IE7. http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

I improove a litle your code but, you need to define exactly what you need.

here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/NMbbS/5/

Css:

```
    html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: black;
}

div {
    width: 48%;
    height: 50%;
    border:1%;
    border: solid #a1a1a1;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```